# Vizdoom: get list with all object names

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I'm using the vizdoom library for an RL project, and I want to get a list with all the possible objects (zombies, objects, etc). I don't want the objects that appear in screen, I need all the objects. Anyone knows how can I do it?